# Why If $Ha=Hb$ then $a=1a=hb$ for some $h\in H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Robert Ash's [*Basic Abstract Algebra.*](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/Algebra.html) There is the following exercise:

> Given cosets $Ha,Hb$, show:
>
> $Ha=Hb \iff ab^{-1}\in H$.

In the book, there is the following answer for one of the implications.

> If $Ha=Hb$ $\huge[$then $a=1a=hb$ for some $h\in H$ $\huge ]$, so $ab^{-1}=h\in H$.

I don't understand how $Ha=Hb$ implies the rest marked in $\huge []$. That seems to be a consequence of $H$ being a group, not of $Ha=Hb$.

---

First, I'd like to say that what follows is - perhaps - not a proof but only a "scratch work" at best.

I have tried to think in terms of the contrapositive $(ab^{-1}\notin H \implies Ha\neq Hb).$ I noticed that not only $ab^{-1}$ need to be in $H$ but $ba^{-1}$ also need to be in $H$. So $Ha=Hb$ means:

- There exists $k$, such that $ah_i=kbh_j$. If $i=j$, then $k=ab^{-1}$.
- There exists $k$, such that $kah_i=bh_j$. If $i=j$, then $k=ba^{-1}$.
- If $ab^{-1},ba^{-1}\notin H$ the previous items are false.

But what if $i\neq j$? Does it make sense to ask this? I don't know how to explain the implication in the given proof and I don't know if in my argument, it makes sense to assume $i=j$.

Comment: You've excluded the possibility that $ab^{-1}\in H$ and $ba^{-1}\notin H$, and vice-versa, not that it makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Ha=Hb$ means every element in $Ha$, in particular $1\cdot a$, is also an element in $Hb$ (and vice-versa), i.e. can be written as $hb$ for some $h\in H$, by definition of a right coset.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. This solved a doubt I had but prefered not to write (where are the 1,a,b,h from?). Now It's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a wonky way to write it.

If $H$ contains an [left] identity (for what I assume is the multiplication operation), then stating $a=I\cdot a$ is largely redundant.

A more intuitive way to write this would be "From $Ha=Hb\implies a=hb$, for some $h\in H$ (definition of [right] coset); it follows that $ab^{-1}=hbb^{-1}$; therefore $ab^{-1}=h$".